# momentjs- subtracting LT while using .format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I can't seem to figure out how to properly subtract two times that I've formatted using this line of code:

```js
var moment = require('moment');
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment();
moment().tz("America/New_York");

clockedIn = moment().tz("America/New_York").format('HH:mm A');

clockedOut = moment().tz("America/New_York").format('HH:mm A');
```

From what I've researched, I can see that using the .format method transforms the time into a string. How would I be able to retain my local time variable and subtract it from another one? I am attempting to build a time punch bot and I have the clockIn/Out routed to an interactive menu with buttons. I am new to this and would appreciate any help/insight.

Comment: Aside: You should only require moment-timezone, and you can short the call to `moment.tz("America/New_York")`.  You don't need lines 1, 3, or 4 above.

Comment: Haha... It does seem a bit redundant when I look at it. Thank you for the heads up, Matt!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but just don't format the data until you actually output it.

```
var clockedIn = moment().tz("America/New_York");
console.log('In: ', clockedIn.format('HH:mm A'));

setTimeout(function() {
    var clockedOut = moment().tz("America/New_York");
    console.log('Out: ', clockedOut.format('HH:mm A'));

    var difference = clockedOut - clockedIn;  // milliseconds
    console.log('Time (secs): ', difference / 1000);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Moment's `diff` function can come in handy here also.

Comment: I see what my issue was! I suppose I did not need to format it until I was ready to display it to the user. I will do some digging into the momentjs docs to make use of the diff function. Thank you so much!